# How can I manage CreateForm with ForeignKey and ManytoMany Relation

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I have one model with ManytoMany relation chained with a ForeignKey.

I want a CreateView, How can I get chained choices or something better thant the generic form ?

The problem with the generic form, is that I get all the "Need[NeedValue]" options and I have to CTRL+Click on each attribute

```py
class Project(models.Model):
        [....]
    needs = models.ManyToManyField("NeedValue", related_name="project_item")


class NeedValue(models.Model):
        [....]
    attribute = models.ForeignKey('Need', verbose_name="Unité", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Need(models.Model):
        [....]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I mean, I my example, When I create a Project, I want to choose one need, and then one value linked to the need.
Or maybe, list all the Needs (with a {% For %}) and ask for the values.

Comment: you'll need to use ajax to get the `NeedValue`s associated with the selected `Need`

Comment: Here you get some inspiration: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: And if you don't like the default browser `<select multiple="multiple">` input widget, use another one. `select2` is popular and there are django packages that integrate it nicely (django-select2, django-autocomplete-light).

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I thought there was a solution without using additional package, or javascript...